# Is there a secret passage in each dungeon in the demo?

Tags: bravely-default-demo

In *Bravely Default* I'm told by a villager that dungeons often have walls I can walk through to find secrets. I found the secret passage in the western cave, are there any others in the other dungeons in the demo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it is only in the Harena Ruins. Using the Freelancer's `Divining Rod` skill to count treasure chests in a dungeon shows that I've opened them all, so there don't seem to be any more hidden passages.

Comment: I could've sworn there was a "secret area" to the left of the map in the Northeast Forest, but it's nearly unaccessible, and I haven't tried all the walls yet

Comment: I saw that clearing too. But my treasure counter said there wasn't anything left to find on that map.

Comment: I think this zone is different in the demo. It looks like it should go on to another map, but the closed it off for the demo.

Comment: @DISREGARDMODSACQUIREREP That area is a backtrack zone from the next left over from when the area was imported from the main game to the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's already well known but I just found one in Twilight Ruins - B1 West

At the first fork in the path from the entrance stairs, it's on the bottom left wall.
I forgot exactly what it gives you though.

Also don't know if this dungeon's available in the demo since I started out with the full version. If it's not then sorry for the mixup.